# REST API URI design conventions

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, api-design

I have a situation where I would like to restrict some APIs only for server to server calls and rest APIs can be called from web browser directly. All the APIs should still be available on internet. What is the best approach for such situation?

http://secureapi.myserver.com/v1/resources
and
http://api.myserver.com/v1/resources

Or

http://api.myserver.com/secure/v1/resources
and
http://api.myserver.com/common/v1/resources

or

http://api.myserver.com/v1/resources 
With a check based on user agent to identify the caller

a better suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: a check based on user agent is not possible?

Comment: that could be another option too.. I am updating the question...

Answer (score 3):

If you want your server-side only API to be really only reachable from the server side, then you'll have to implement a proper access control model. Have your API clients submit `Authorization` headers with their HTTP requests so that the server can accurately distinguish between trusted server-side callers and browsers out on the web.

Don't rely on spoofable things like User Agent strings. That's security through obscurity and is guaranteed to bite you later.

Just remember that these two wishes of yours:

> I would like to restrict some APIs only for server to server calls

and

> All the APIs should still be available on internet.

are what scream out for a properly designed secure auth layer for your API.

Comment: Adding to that, you could also look into OAuth2.0 with JWT for server to server authentication/authorization along with "ContainerRequestFilter" for filtering the requests, if you are using jersey for REST implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The implementation is using Microsoft's ASP.NET WebApi.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) mechanism. Configure it on your REST API to use CORS.

More information here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx

Comment: Thanks Regfor, that addresses the implementation part of the question. Any suggestions on what the end points should look like purely from the end developers point of view. Shall it be two different URI structure or same URI structure but different internal security. Just trying to think of some intuitive.

Comment: @RajatMehta It will be better when URLs will be similar (or same structure), but it depends on your resources and hosting. But even if they due to some restrictions or requirements will be different, I suggest to keep some concept the same - for example versioning in URI.
First and second examples from your question are good. I will keep separate "secure" CORS api and public api. BTW when this CORS endpoint are restricted to your services, you can save some performance and not validate Authorization header token for them, because they are restricted to be called only from "full trust" servers.